# Why is free(usr_input) not working?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm getting an error with `free()` every time I store input above the allocated space in the `char*`. Here is the error:

```
 Error in ./input': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09713008
```

When I remove the `free()`, the program runs perfectly even though I'm entering more than the allocated size. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it? Here is my code for reference:

```
int main(void){

  float x; // used to store the float the user entered.
  char c; // character used to check if the user entered a character after the float
  int loop=0;

  char * usr_input = malloc(50); //allocates memory to store the string from the stdin

  // loops until the user enters a float and only a float
  do{
    //gets the input string from stdin
    scanf("%s",usr_input);

    if(usr_input==NULL)
        printf("You've entered a large number that isnt supported. Please use at most 5 digits\n");

    // parses the input received and checks if the user entered a float and only a float.
    // breaks the loop if they did
    else if(sscanf(usr_input,"%f %c",&x,&c) == 1){
        if (x!=inf)
            loop=1;
        else
            printf("Input was too large. Try again");
    }

    // tells the user they entered invalid input. Loop value doesnt change so function loops again
    else{
        printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
    }
  }

  while(loop==0); // condition for the loop
  free(usr_input);//crashes here
  return x; // returns the valid float that was entered
}
```

Comment: `if(usr_input==NULL)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't leave a blank line between the `}` and the `while` of a `do … while` loop; it is too easy to misread it.  Some people put the `while` on the same line as the `}`; others put it on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You're corrupting the heap - everything else is just undefined behaviour. Change:

```
scanf("%s",usr_input);
```

to:

```
scanf("%49s",usr_input);
```

and then you will not be able to overflow your input buffer.

---

Also note that this makes no sense:

```
if(usr_input==NULL)
    printf("You've entered a large number that isnt supported. Please use at most 5 digits\n");
```

You should probably change it to something like this:

```
if (strlen(usr_input) > 5)
    printf("You've entered a large number that isnt supported. Please use at most 5 digits\n");
```